# Why didn't survey corps climb on top of the walls to avoid boulders of beast titan season 3 part 2

Tags: anime-production, attack-on-titan, manga-production

When beast titan was throwing boulders at the survey corps, he could only destroy the building outside of the wall.  Why didn't scouts use their odm gear, climb the walls, and get on the other side of the wall to avoid beast titan's boulders?

Answer (score 1):

Because doing so would merely have doomed them to die more slowly.

By retreating over the wall the Survey Corps would have been abandoning their horses to die leaving them with no way to leave the area safely.

On foot they would have no chance at all to reach the Beast Titan without being crushed by the boulders nor would they have any hope of returning to Wall Rose in a single night meaning that even if they could somehow evade the Beast Titan they would be at the mercy of any normal Titan roaming the area.

Their options if they'd taken shelter would have been starve to death or make an even more suicidal charge while all the Beast Titan would need to do to win would be sit back and wait.

Answer (score 0):

The survey corps retreating into the wall is a death sentence. On the other side of the wall is the colossal titan. Zekes plan is to encircle them from both sides of the wall. If they run away with their horses, they'd be obliterated by Zeke's titan group. If they scale the wall and move to the other side, there is the colossal and armored titan. If they run on top of the wall, they would still need to go down and cross the titan territory, on foot, to get to Wall Rose. Staying on the wall is just slow death. That is why Levi suggested to have Eren, in titan form, carry as many soldiers as possible and run for retreat, using the remaining corp members and himself as decoy. Which has very low chance of success too.

And this is why Erwin is a genius. He used the enemy's advantage as a weapon. And by that I mean using the wall of titans as Levi's path towards the Beast titan. Thereby turning the tide of the battle. Costly but genius.